# Axios post request failing with a 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, axios

I'm using Axios to query an endpoint in my backend. When I try and do this, I get a 404 not found. If I copy/paste the uri it gives in the error from the console and try and access it directly in the browser it connects fine and does not give me an error (instead giving me an empty object which is expected).

Below is my Axios code

```
axios.post("/api/myEndpoint", { id: this.userID })
      .then((response) => { 
        this.property = response.data.property;
      })
      .catch((errors) => {    
        console.log(errors);    
        router.push("/");    
      });
```

Below is the route definition in my backend

```
const myEndpointRoute = require('../api/myEndpoint.js')();
exprApp.use('/api/myEndpoint', myEndpointRoute);
```

For reference, the uri is 'http://localhost:3000/api/myEndpoint'. I can access this uri completely fine in the browser but Axios returns a 404 as described above. It is for this reason that I'm confident this is an issue in the frontend, however I have set up this Axios request in the same way as the many others I have and they all work fine.

Edit: here's the rest of the backend

myEndpoint.js

```
module.exports = function() {
const express = require('express'), router = express.Router();
const authMiddleware = require('../loaders/authMiddleware.js')();

router.get('/', authMiddleware, async function(req, res) {
  const id = req.body.id;

  const property = await require('../services/myEndpointService.js') 
    (id).catch((e) => { console.log(e) });
    res.send({ property: property });
  });

  return router;
};
```

myEndpointService.js

```
module.exports = async function(id) {
  const results = await require('../models/getMyEndpointProperty')(id);

  return results;
};
```

getMyEndpointProperty

```
module.exports = async function(id) {
  const pool = require('../loaders/pool.js')();

  const res = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = ${id};`);
  return res.rows;
};
```

Comment: Can you show *myEndpoint.js*?

Comment: I've added some extra backend info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*myEndpoint.js* defines only a `GET` method but your axios call sends a `POST` in the frontend.  Try changing (or adding) the express route:

```js
// notice the `.post`
router.post('/', authMiddleware, async function(req, res) {
...
})
```

It worked when you manually tested it in the browser for this reason as well, since the browser sent a `GET` request.

Comment: Thank you, I must have looked over that file 1000 times and not noticed